# SVN working copy is locked

Tags: svn, drupal

Ok, so I can't even describe the hell I've been going through for the past hours.

I'm managing a drupal website, I have a working copy locally and one on a staging server.
While I was working on it I decided to update the Drupal core, without really thinking I just copied all Drupal files into my working copy, everything worked fine locally until I wanted to commit everything to svn.

I use Cornerstone to do this, but all my folders are now obstructed, when I try to do a cleanup I get this error "... is not a working copy directory".

I then tried moving all updated folders to somewhere else to delete them first from svn, which suddenly gave me this error: "... does not exist" (why?? I'm trying to delete it ...)

So now I'm basically stuck, I can't commit, I can't update, I can't cleanup, can't do anything basically.

I don't want to check out again since my local version is newer, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after much trying around, these are the steps I did:

1. Remove all the updated folders
2. Add back the old folders
3. Remove them through svn
4. commit
5. Add back updated folders
6. Commit